# Laravel 6 null coalescing operator gives Undefined variable: user when calling a method on it?

Tags: php, laravel, null-coalescing-operator

I'm trying to get this working.

```
<option value="{{$role->id}}" {{ (collect(old('userrole') ?? $user->roles()->pluck('id')->implode(", ") ?? '')->contains($role->id)) ? 'selected':'' }}>{{$role->name}}</option>
```

For some reason it won't work. It gives back the error: Undefined variable: user.

Any help?

Comment: Can you share more code to solve the query?

Comment: you don't want to implode the ids into a string ... `collect('1,2,3')->contains(3)` .. that won't work .. you will get a false positive for `contains(1)` though because `1 == '1, 2, 3'` of how PHP converts that string to a number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The null-coalescing operator `??` will check if the final result is null or not - it will not take into consideration any variables that may be undeclared to obtain that result.

You can therefor use a ternary operator to see if the `$roles` value is set or not for that expression.

```
{{ (collect(
           old('userrole') 
             ?? (isset($user) 
                     ? $user->roles()->pluck('id')->implode(", ") 
                     : ''
                 )
            )->contains($role->id)) 
             ? 'selected'
             : '' }}
```

The `old()` helper also takes a second parameter, as "default" should the value not exist, which you can use. And since you're looking for a single value, the usage of a ternary operator to output `selected` can be replaced by a blade `@if` block.

```
<option value="{{$role->id}}" 
    @if (collect(old('userrole', (isset($user) ? $user->roles()->pluck('id')->implode(", ") : ''))->contains($role->id)))
        selected
    @endif 
>{{$role->name}}</option>
```

You can also reduce som cluttering in the code by using `contains()` on the object itself (without having to `pluck()` the id`).

```
<option value="{{ $role->id }}" 
    @if (collect(old('userrole', (isset($user) ? $user->roles())->contains($role->id)))
        selected
    @endif 
>{{ $role->name }}</option>
```